# Вставка картинки в html-код в Django.

Tags: django-orm, django-admin, django

Здравствуйте! Такая проблема возникла. Через Django administrator загружаются картинки на сервер, в базу при этом пишется путь загруженной картинки.

А когда я хочу вставить эту картинку в хтмл файл таким вот образом

```
<img src={% static "{{ image }}" %}>
```

То при этом в исходном html-коде вместо адреса получается что-то вроде

```
<img src=/static/%7B%7B%20image%20%7D%7D>
```

В чем проблема? Если прописать адрес явно

```
<img src={% static "img/1.jpg" %}>
```

все работает, как и должно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы как-то странно передаете переменную. `{% static image %}` тогда уж.

З.Ы. Только аплоад нужно класть не в static, а в media, тогда будет `{{ image.url }}`, как и должно.

Comment: Точно, сработали оба варианта, на счет media буду знать, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте передать image.file или как у вас названо поле для файла. Похоже, что сейчас вы передаете весь объект.

Comment: в файле views.py код такой:  
      
    item = Product.objects.get(id=item_id)
        item_info = {
        'image': item.image,
    }

если в html-код встроить переменную {{ image }}, то он отображает все корректно. т.е.

на такой html-код:
    
        {{ image }}
        <img src= "{% static "{{ image }}" %}"/>
вот такая реакция
    
        static/img/1.jpg
        <img src= "/static/%7B%7B%20image%20%7D%7D"/>

Comment: т.е. объектом у меня является
    item
полем, где содержится ссылка является поле
    image
т.е. обращение 
    item.image
вроде, именно такое, как вы сказали...